# Working with Eclipse's internal browser

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the code below to try and open the internal browser of Eclipse. However, it appears as a separate window. Is there a way to make it appear as a window in the UI or not separate?

```
    Display display = Display.getCurrent();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
    browser.addTitleListener(new TitleListener() {
        public void changed(TitleEvent event) {
            shell.setText(event.title);
        }
    });
    browser.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    browser.setUrl("http://google.com");

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creating a new `Shell` creates a new window. You just put the browser control directly in the view / editor / dialog like any other control if you don't want a new window.

Comment: So what would I give as a parameter here     Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE) instead of the shell?

Comment: Whatever composite control you want to put the Browser in. You haven't given us anything like enough information to tell you any more. Is this an Eclipse plugin? Are you writing a standalone SWT program?

Comment: Yes it is an eclipse plugin and I don't know how to get the composite control of my plugin.

Comment: Your plugin doesn't have any UI components until you create them. You will need to create a view or an editor or a dialog triggered from a menu item.